Angular 18 customising theme issue
I am trying to migrate some code from my angular 16 project to the updated version which is now angular 18
Below is what has been implemented and I keep getting compilation errors from
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

// Define custom palettes for NAPSA colors
$napsa-blue: (
  50: #e4e6ec,
  100: #bcc0d0,
  200: #9096b0,
  300: #646b90,
  400: #424c79,
  500: #212c61,
  600: #1d2759,
  700: #18214f,
  800: #141b45,
  900: #0b1033,
  A100: #6e7cff,
  A200: #3b4eff,
  A400: #0820ff,
  A700: #0016ee,
  contrast: (
    50: #000000,
    100: #000000,
    200: #000000,
    300: #ffffff,
    400: #ffffff,
    500: #ffffff,
    600: #ffffff,
    700: #ffffff,
    800: #ffffff,
    900: #ffffff,
    A100: #000000,
    A200: #ffffff,
    A400: #ffffff,
    A700: #ffffff,
  ),
);

$napsa-orange: (
  50: #fef4e3,
  100: #fee4ba,
  200: #fdd28c,
  300: #fcc05e,
  400: #fbb33c,
  500: #faa519,
  600: #f99d16,
  700: #f99312,
  800: #f88a0e,
  900: #f67908,
  A100: #ffffff,
  A200: #fff4eb,
  A400: #ffd7b8,
  A700: #ffc89f,
  contrast: (
    50: #000000,
    100: #000000,
    200: #000000,
    300: #000000,
    400: #000000,
    500: #000000,
    600: #000000,
    700: #000000,
    800: #000000,
    900: #000000,
    A100: #000000,
    A200: #000000,
    A400: #000000,
    A700: #000000,
  ),
);

// Define palettes using the new theming API
$light-primary: mat.define-palette($napsa-blue);
$light-accent: mat.define-palette($napsa-orange);
$dark-primary: mat.define-palette($napsa-blue);
$dark-accent: mat.define-palette($napsa-orange);

// Define themes using mat.createTheme()
$light-theme: mat.create-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $light-primary,
    accent: $light-accent,
    background: mat.define-palette(mat.$grey-palette),
  )
));

$dark-theme: mat.create-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $dark-primary,
    accent: $dark-accent,
    background: mat.define-palette(mat.$grey-palette, 900),
  ),
  is-dark: true
));

// Apply all component themes for the light theme
@include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);

and this is the error I keep getting
Undefined function.
   ╷
72 │ $light-primary: mat.define-palette($napsa-blue);
   │                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src/napsa.scss 72:17  root stylesheet

./src/napsa.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined function.
   ╷
71 │ $light-primary: mat.define-palette($napsa-blue);
   │                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src/napsa.scss 71:17  root stylesheet



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


✖ Failed to compile.```


Angular 18 introduces M3 theming which is also the new default. If you want to continue to use M2 theming, you need to prefix some of the Sass symbols with m2- (see the M2 theming docs):
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$light-primary: mat.m2-define-palette($napsa-blue);
$light-accent: mat.m2-define-palette($napsa-orange);
$dark-primary: mat.m2-define-palette($napsa-blue);
$dark-accent: mat.m2-define-palette($napsa-orange);

$light-theme: mat.m2-define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $light-primary,
    accent: $light-accent,
    background: mat.m2-define-palette(mat.$grey-palette),
  )
));

$dark-theme: mat.m2-define-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $dark-primary,
    accent: $dark-accent,
    background: mat.m2-define-palette(mat.$grey-palette, 900),
  ),
));

Or if you want to create a custom M3 theme, you can run the M3 theme creation schematics:
ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme

